# Modifying Wordpress plugin - Paid Memberships Pro for added functionality

Tags: paypal, wordpress

I need to modify a Wordpress plugin (Paid Memberships Pro) so that it can make provision for an alternate (added) payment system apart from the credit card payment (using pre-assigned codes, something like login code.)

This is to enable to users without credit cards to have access to the privileged sections of my site.

I have figured out how to generate the codes to be used as the logins but I'm totally lost at merging this concept into the wordpress plugin as an add-on.

Answer (score 0):

This is Jason Coleman, the lead developer of Paid Memberships Pro. Sorry if you asked this question in our own support forums and didn't get a speedy answer (http://www.paidmembershipspro.com/support/).

PMPro has discount codes included, which would be perfect for this. Simply create a discount code that changes the price to $0 for the level and hand out that code. Ask people to sign up for an account using the code.

Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: @Jason: Thanks for the tip. Sorry I'm replying so late. I'm actually trying to figure out a way to create a payment option for those who don't have credit cards or would prefer cash payment as an alter-option.